# recursion in parsing

Tags: parsing, bison, lex

Here are input file, .l file , .y file and output.

problem is that parser is not able to identify the directions recursively..

it is identifying just first...

i've used same rule for recognizing ports and its working

but not in case of direction..

also it is not displaying .y file code associated with rule(cout statement)

**input file .**

```
start a b c d                //ports

a:O b:I c:B d:O    //direction of ports
```

**.l file**

```
[\t]+                   {}

[\n]  {line_num++; cout"line_num:" line_num; }

start                   {  cout< "beggining of file"; return START;}



[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+:[IOB]    {cout<<"\ndirection:" << strdup(yytext); return DR; }

[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+     {cout<<"\nfound name:" strdup(yytext); return NAME;}
```

**.y file grammer**

```
doc : START ports dir

ports : NAME ports  { cout<<"\port in .y" $1;}

        | NAME    { cout<<"\nport in .y" $1;}
        ;


dir : DR dir       { cout<<"\ndirection in .y" $1;}

    | DR            { cout<<"\ndirection in .y"<<$1;    }
    ;
```

**output is .**

beginning of file

```
found name:a

found name:b

found name:c 

found name:d

 line no-2

direction:a:O
```

Comment: I don't see a lex rule that discards ordinary spaces, that is, I see `[\t]+` where I would expect to see `[ \t]+`, or simply `\s+`.  Are you sure that the second line of your input file is delimited with tabs, not spaces?

Comment: [\t]+ is perfectly working... I've used this rule many times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only clear error you're making is that you are not setting the value of `yylval` in your flex actions, so `$1` is some uninitialized value in all of your bison actions. Your flex actions should look something like this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+     { yylval = strdup(text);
                      cout  <<  "\nfound name:" << yylval;
                      return NAME;
                    }
```

Also, make sure you specify that the type of the tokens `DR` and `NAME` is `const char *`.

Finally, don't forget to `free()` the strings when you don't need them any more.